# What does "Maximum request size of document and attachment" mean in Azure DocumentDB limitations?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are planning to use Azure DocumentDB. Therefore I am checking its limitations. On page [DocumentDB Limits](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/), it says that "Maximum request size of document and attachment: 512KB". What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Documents have size limits. As you build your collection's documents, you are limited to a certain size per document per document. If you create a document larger than the maximum size, and attempt to store it in your collection, you'll receive an error.

This limit has nothing to do with maximum number of documents stored within a collection, or with the number of collections you create.

**EDIT 4/2017** The per-document limit is no longer 512K. I believe it is 2MB now.

Comment: David, do you know if there is a way to send in separately (via stream) an attachment larger than 512K? When I look at the docs, you can send in a stream for the body of an attachment creation. If you do that, can it be larger than 512K? I know the azure blob storage holds up to 200GB blobs and I thought that's what backed DocumentDB's attachment functionality.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone If you need to store objects larger than 512k it is far more efficient to store them directly as a blob and then simply have a reference to that file in DocumentDB. The maximum storage size for DocumentDB is 512k there's no way around that.

Comment: DocumentDB has two methods of dealing with attachments

1) as a managed attachment. this is where you stream the content of the attachment through the DocumentDB client api. it will store this as an attachment, in blob storage. 

2) as a linked attachment. here, instead of streaming the blob content through DocumentDB you store the content wherever you like and use the Uri for that as the mediaLink property in the DocumentDB attachment.

Comment: You can even drop the use of attachments completely and just simply store the Url as a field in your JSON document.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone if you use managed attachments, the binary for the attachment is not counted toward the 512K size limit. That is purely the size of the document itself. And yes, the binary is stored under the covers in blob storage. Each account is allocated 2Gb of attachment storage.

Comment: @Ryan, thanks for the detailed answer. Two more questions: 1) Do you mean GigaByte when you say 2Gb? I thought the lower-case "b" meant bits instead of bytes which would make it 1/8 the limit? 2) Why is the limit per account as opposed to per collection since that's the entity that correlates with cost? I haven't started using attachments yet but I have a use case on our backlog that would be ideal. However, if the limit is really 2Gb or even 2GB per account, I'll do as you and David suggest and store it myself.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone I think it's time to post a new question. Comments aren't the place to post new questions and have all this info buried here. Not the byte-vs-bit question of course (it's byte).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Why the usage of the "request" in the limit explanation? Why don't they just use "Maximum size of document and attachment"?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [BISON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) (Binary JSON). It is supported in json.net.

There is also [base85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85)

Another possible solution is to split your documents.  Create a master document, with an array of child document id's

Just store the attachment data in the child documents.

Comment: I think JSON.net supports BSON, not BISON. BSON is often larger in size than JSON.